# CUDA video card

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, video-quality, hardware

I am new to After Effects. Just did my first real project - lots of fun. I am not that happy with my encoding output quality. Is it true that having a CUDA video card - i.e. rendering in hardware - improves QUALITY of output as well as speed? How much of a difference does it make?

Comment: It can give a significant speed boost, but I don't believe you'd see better quality -- rather a little bit the opposite in my experience, for a given bit rate.

Comment: I read somewhere on line that the video card makes a difference in quality of encoding output. But it makes absolutely no sense to me and I am very skeptical.

Comment: Because it can increase speed, you can get better quality given the same encoding time. You can trade quality for encoding time whether or not you're using a CUDA card, and since CUDA is faster the tradeoff would be less costly. Maybe that's what what you read was referring to.